# Can you use decltype in a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype, trailing-return-type

I am trying to overload a multiplication operator but do not want to type out multiple overloaded functions to take into account multiplying int and float, int and double, float and int, etc... I was hoping to write one overloaded operator to account for all combinations of multiplication with floats, ints, and doubles and get the proper return type. I am getting errors saying that no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Widget::Widget' (or there is no acceptable conversion). I think this is because I am using the decltype to set the template type of the return object, the Widget. Using a trailing return type works if the return is not a template object.

Here is an example of the overloaded operator I am trying to make:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto
operator*(const Widget<T1>& aWidge, const Widget<T2>& bWidge) -> Widget<decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)>
{
    Widget<decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)> result;

    //do stuff needed when multiplying two Widgets

    return result;
}

template<typename T>
Widget<T>& Widget<T>::operator=(const Widget<T>& aWidget)
{
    x = aWidget.x;

    return *this;
}
```

And here is an example of the template class

```
template<typename T> class Widget
{
    private:
        T x;
    public:
        Widget();
        ~Widget();
        void SetX(T value);
        Widget<T>& operator=(const Widget<T>& aWidget);
}
```

Example Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    Widget<int> aWidge;
    Widget<float> bWidge;
    Widget<float> cWidge;

    aWidge.SetX(2);
    bWidge.SetX(2.0);

    cWidge = aWidge*bWidge; //this should give a float return type
}
```

Comment: I'd start by fixing your `operator =` for `Widget<T>` to properly resolve the *member* operator, i.e. `Widget<T>& Widget<T>::operator=(const Widget<T>& aWidget)`

Comment: Did you try to compile? If so, what happened?

Comment: That's a template argument, not a template parameter.

Comment: @WhozCraig happy? Can you try answering my question instead of concentrating on typos of a demo class?

Comment: @user3390212: Don't miss the point. The more typos you make, the more of our time you waste. Get it right first, _then_ post and ask for help with it. Also drop the _entitled_ attitude, your highness.

Comment: It works for me (after I fix the obvious problems: define `operator=` properly, use `declval<T1>()` (etc.) instead of `aWidge.x` to get around private variable access, define/default the missing functions).  Perhaps you can post a minimal compilable example that illustrates the problem, along with the compiler, version, and platform you're on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012

Don't mind the sloppy code. It was a quick fix for code that didn't compile properly to begin with (nevermind the auto decltype problem).

```
template<typename T>
class Widget
{
public:
    T x;
public:
    Widget()
        : x(666)
    {}

    ~Widget() {}

    void SetX(T value)
    {
        x = value;
    }

    Widget<T>& operator=(const Widget<T>& aWidget)
    {
        x = aWidget.x;

        return *this;
    }
};


template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(const Widget<T1>& aWidge, const Widget<T2>& bWidge) -> Widget<typename std::remove_const<decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)>::type>
{
    Widget<typename std::remove_const<decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)>::type> result;

    result.x = aWidge.x * bWidge.x;

    return result;
}



int main ()
{
    Widget<int> aWidge;
    Widget<float> bWidge;
    Widget<float> cWidge;

    aWidge.SetX(2);
    bWidge.SetX(2.0);

    cWidge = aWidge*bWidge; //this should give a float return type
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a perfect answer to my problem, although I was wondering if you could explain the reason why the decltype(expression) needed to be declared a typename? I thought that decltype would give the return type of the expression inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @user3390212 Wasn't `x` meant to be `private`? Otherwise, what is the purpose of `SetX()`?

Comment: It was, but since the code didn't compile, I did a quick hack to make it compile. Making it public was orthogonal to dealing with the OP's decltype problem.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the error message carefully, the problem is obvious:

```
candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T1 = int, T2 = float]: 'x' is
      a private member of 'Widget<int>'
```

Non-member binary `operator*` is trying to access private member `x` in its declaration (and definition). Since you have a setter function, a plain solution is to also define a getter and only access member `x` through this function:

```
template<typename T> class Widget
{
    private:
        T x;

    public:
        Widget() {}
        ~Widget() {}
        void SetX(T value) {}
        T& GetX() { return x; }
        const T& GetX() const { return x; }
        Widget<T>& operator=(const Widget<T>& aWidget);
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto
operator*(const Widget<T1>& aWidge, const Widget<T2>& bWidge)
-> Widget<decltype(aWidge.GetX()*bWidge.GetX())>
{
    Widget<decltype(aWidge.GetX()*bWidge.GetX())> result;
    //...
    return result;
}
```

Another option would be to make `operator*` a friend:

```
template<typename T> class Widget
{
    private:
        T x;

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    friend auto
    operator*(const Widget<T1>& aWidge, const Widget<T2>& bWidge)
    -> Widget<decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)>;

    public:
        Widget() {}
        ~Widget() {}
        void SetX(T value) {}
        Widget<T>& operator=(const Widget<T>& aWidget);
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto
operator*(const Widget<T1>& aWidge, const Widget<T2>& bWidge)
-> Widget<decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)>
{
    Widget<decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)> result;

    return result;
}
```

or, make it a member function (thanks WhozCraig).

You will probably also need

```
typename std::decay<decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)>::type
```

instead of just `decltype(aWidge.x*bWidge.x)`.

Other options are

```
typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T1>()*std::declval<T2>())>::type
```

which bypasses the previous problem entirely (thanks Adam), or just

```
typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type
```

which should fit for this purpose and is arguably the simplest form.

Comment: +1 A third option would be just make it a member and friend all `template<class T> class Widget;`. Any of the above work (I prefer the latter in this specific case, though I prefer free-functions in general).

Comment: Sure, thanks. For many reasons I also prefer free functions accessing data through a public interface so that no friends are needed. For this case I am not sure, but starting from `operator*` I can't see why not defining ~20-30 more operators (!) which, being members, would be harder to compile.

Comment: If I could up vote this again i would, especially noteworthy on the tailing mention of [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type). I think the argument of whether that is the simplest form would be a short one. It clearly is so. Super nice answer.